# where to find unhide-tcp for centos 6?

Tags: centos, yum

I've got a centOS 6 64 bit server, and have installed rkhunter.

I spent some time running scans and tweaking things so that rkhunter throws up no warnings (e.g setting the PermitRootLogin var in /etc/rkhunter.conf to the same value as in my sshd.conf, and running `rkhunter --propupd`), however I still have one thing popping up in the logs:

```
872059-[10:57:36] Info: Starting test name 'hidden_ports'
872110:[10:57:36] Checking for hidden ports                         [ Skipped ]
872183-[10:57:36] Info: Unable to find the 'unhide-tcp' command
```

After a bit of googling, it seems I need to install the `unhide` package so rkhunter can check for hidden ports. But I haven't been able to figure out where to get it - I've added the `rpmforge` repo which apparently did have it at some point, but when I try to install or search for it:

```
$ sudo yum install unhide unhide-tcp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.as29550.net
 * extras: mirror.as29550.net
 * rpmforge: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
 * updates: centosn4.centos.org
Setting up Install Process
No package unhide available.
No package unhide-tcp available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Anyone know what repo I need to add, or even if `unhide` is still in existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find Unhide in RepoForge http://repoforge.org/use/ also you can download the latest versions in their homepage http://www.unhide-forensics.info

Answer (score -1):

There is NO separate EL6 X64 version of Unhide in Repoforge at 1 July 2013.

http://pkgs.repoforge.org/unhide/

unhide-0.0.20110113-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm   06-Apr-2012 16:57  280K  RHEL5 and CentOS-5 x86 32bit
unhide-0.0.20110113-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm 06-Apr-2012 16:57  294K  RHEL5 and CentOS-5 x86 64bit

unhide-0.0.20110113-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm   06-Apr-2012 16:57  250K  RHEL6 and CentOS-6 x86

http://www.unhide-forensics.info/?Linux:Download

states "Current Stable Version: 2012-12-29"

Always Learning.

Comment: -1. this is the version I installed, it's still there apparently... http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm. This should be a comment on the accepted answer rather than an answer itself as it does not solve the question.